# Vuetify don't render on cordova android

Tags: android, cordova, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've created a Vue project and add a cordova plugin, like this:

```
vue create app-test
vue add cordova
npm run cordova-serve-android
```

Everything works up to this point.

Then I've tried to do this:

```
vue add vuetify
```

When I run:

```
npm run cordova-serve-browser
```

Everything fine, but when I run

```
npm run cordova-serve-android
```

Just a blank screen was rendered

Examining the code with the debugger, there's no App.vue, nor HelloWorld.vue instantiated.

I've just find a lot of errors on console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
https://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1570409595173
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

How It worked for me (without using vue cordova plugin)

1. Remove and install new version nodejs and cordova
2. Created a cordova project and added  platform android (don't build or run android from the command prompt.. it will create lot of errors)
3. Then open the created android project (\platforms\android) in android studio (use the latest version of android studio),on open it will ask for gradle upgrade, then "Ok" to update the build gradle and wait for the update finish.
4. then run the project from android studio,
5. if the cordova hellworld project is working, then replace the content of 'platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\www\' with the content in 'dist' folder created by using the vuejs build command.
6. Then run the project from the android again, Now you can view your app
7. (optional) if you are sending non https requests from the app, then  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the AndroidManifest.xml file

   Note : You have to build the vuetify project every time to generate 'dist' folder and need replace the files in www folder